# Cannot get Source RPM for Centos 5.8 Packages

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I am trying to use yumdownloader , but getting error:

```
$ yumdownloader --source ntp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
No source RPM found for ntp-4.2.2p1-15.el5.centos.1.i386
Nothing to download

$ yumdownloader --source openssh
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
No source RPM found for openssh-4.3p2-82.el5.i386
Nothing to download
```

I am on CentOs 5.8 . Any ideas ? I have looked at lots of web sites, but none of the solutions for .repo file works

It seems CentOs has moved their Source RPMs to Vault ( vault.centos.org ) 
But i am not sure on how to setup the /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SRPMS.repo file
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: display me output of this commands `yum search openssh` and `yum repolist`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your source repo uses the wrong version, or is still configured as if Johnny et al wanted to make it less than a hassle to grab old SRPMs.  Hit http://vault.centos.org/5.8/updates/SRPMS/ by hand, or adjust your /etc/yum.repos.d/foo.repo files to suit.